# Redis Support on Secondary index

Tags: redis

Does redis provide support for secondary index on string data type?

I have installed redis server to check that, but could not find out clearly to do this.

I would like to know how i can store the data in redis along with seconday key.

Example let say i want to store thevehicle id:- registration no, in my case this will be primary key, vehicle color:- Red, this could be secondary key and payload related to vehicle info is my value. Now, I also want to find all payload whose color is red in redis.

Same as like i can do in MySql like

Select * from table where secondarycolumn="red"

Also, I would like to know while setting value in redis using primary key, how can i set the secondary index value for it.

Comment: You must be looking for the Hash data type. Check out HSET command (and a large family of other commands that begins with H)

Comment: Did you check http://redisearch.io?

Comment: I would like to know how i can store the data in redis along with seconday key.
Example

let say i want to store the following vechile 

vehicle id:- registration no, in my case this will be primary key
vehicle color:- Red, this could be secondary key

and payload related to vehicle info is my value.

**Now, I also want to find all payload whose color is red in redis.** 


@glee8e

Comment: ZeeSQL (formerly RediSql) is by far the best solution for the use case, I use it myself, and its great. See Siscias answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add support for secondary index in Redis by deploying the [RediSearch](http://redisearch.io/).

RediSearch supports defining automatic indexing of the hash fields and then to easily query those indexes using a simple query phrase.

e.g

```
FT.SEARCH myIdx "@name:Joe @age:[70-90]"
```

Comment: Does Redisearch support ACL and RBac?

Comment: Yes with Redis ACL

Answer (score 1):

For secondary index you can use Hash data type.
eg:

to store:

```
HSET myindex akash Manuel
```

To get:

```
HGET myindex akash
```

this will return: `Manuel`

check this link: [Redis Hash](https://redis.io/commands/hset)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Ruhul. My question is i have primary key "pk1" and secondary index  "secin" and value is akash

I want to store the data using primary ket and secondary key also. 
But i might want to get the key using secondary index.

something like this

SET "pk1" "secin" akash
GET pk1 should return akash
GET secin should return akash.

Comment: I guess redis did not support directly what you are wanting. You can check this link: https://redis.io/topics/indexes

Answer (score 0):

zeeSQL is a novel Redis module that introduces exactly secondary indexing.

This allows the developer to set up once the fields they want to index and just let the module do all the book-keeping around maintaining the index.

In your particular case, the very first step would be to [create a new zeeSQL database](https://doc.zeesql.com/references#zeesql-create_db).

```
> ZEESQL.CREATE_DB Vehicles
OK
```

Then you will [instruct zeeSQL to keep a secondary index for all the Vehicles and their color](https://doc.zeesql.com/references#zeesql-index-new).

```
> ZEESQL.INDEX Vehicles NEW PREFIX vehicles:* TABLE Registrations SCHEMA color STRING
OK
```

Then, you can insert new values in the Redis Hash with:

```
> HMSET vehicles:12344 color red
OK
> HMSET vehicles:11334 color blue
OK
```

The values are stored in both Redis but also in the zeeSQL secondary indexes.

The secondary indexes of zeeSQL is a simple SQLite table, that you can then query, for instance with with [ZEESQL.QUERY command](https://doc.zeesql.com/references#zeesql-query).

```
> ZEESQL.QUERY Vehicles COMMAND "SELECT * FROM Registrations WHERE color = 'red';"
```

A deeper [explanation  on how to create Redis secondary index using zeeSQL is also available here](https://doc.zeesql.com/secondary-indexes).