# Redis get key by value (Secondary index or another solution)

Tags: redis

I have a table with id-token as a key-value. Sometimes I need to get id by token (when a user is logging).

How I can do this?

I can create a separate table (namespace) with a token as key and id as data, but it not seems like a good approach.
I heard about the secondary index as a solution, but I can't find out how to create them and what the difference between approaches in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56542048/14190526) question.
Which one should I use for my task?

Comment: You can either build your own 2ndary index using the methods described at the [Redis Indexes](https://redis.io/topics/indexes) page or use something ready-made such as a Redis ORM-like framework (look at the bottom of https://redis.io/clients) or a Redis module (as suggested in the referenced question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can create a separate table with a token as key and id as data

This is a way of creating secondary index. In most cases this is a better solution. Because this way you won't need any other dependency. Moreover, you would have full control over the index (data).

Comment: Is redis has a possibility to add expiration time on a secondary index row? This is critical for me

Comment: Which secondary index you're meaning here? If you mean the "manual" one and if you use string (data structure) instead of hash, you can add expiration yourself.

Comment: @ sazzad Thank u, I thought that splitting data (by a colon) is a bad idea.

Comment: @salius glad to help